# How to hide Download Link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, download, hide

The site fmovies offers to download a video with a download button under the video (for example http://fmovies.to/film/designated-survivor.qxz83/42jp6m).

When I look in the HTML code or all the js scripts, I can't find the download link? How do they hide the downloadlink and where do they hide it?

Is there an other way to get this download link?

*EDIT: NOT the "Download in HD" button, I meant the "Download" Button right next to the Report Button (left of it). You have to wait a few Seconds until the Player has loaded.*

Comment: `all.js` is obfuscated. The code to add it could be in there, and it would be very difficult to find.

Comment: Thanks, i deobfuscated it, is it possible to get the download link now (https://jsfiddle.net/2yzajvch/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the download butt, it goes to the following HTML:

```
<div class="item mbtn download-movie pull-right" style=""> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download </div>
```

In the de-obfuscated `all.js`, this class is:

```
    FL = ".download-movie",
```

and searching for references to that variable we find:

```
this.$btnDownload = e[Ue](FL)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
this.$btnDownload = e.find(".download-movie")
```

It's also referenced in this code:

```
        hideMovieActions: function() {
            this.$btnDownload.unbind(Eo)[du](), this.$btnDownloadSubtitle.unbind(Eo)[du]()
        },
```

which is equivalent to:

```
        hideMovieActions: function() {
            this.$btnDownload.unbind("click").hide(), this.$btnDownloadSubtitle.unbind("click").hide()
        },
```

so that's the code that hides the download button.

I can't find the code that shows it, or the code that runs when you click on it. That seems to be hidden in several additional layers of obfuscation. They really didn't want to make it easy for you to figure out how their code works.

Answer (score 2):

Its not hidden. If you are using chrome right click the button and click inspect and you will see it. It looks something like:

```
<a class="full btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://fmovies.to/player/download_in_hd.html?movie=designated-survivor" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download in HD </a>
```

Comment: EDIT: NOT the "Download in HD" button, I meant the "Download" Button right next to the Report Button (left of it). You have to wait a few Seconds until the Player has loaded.

Comment: The download button is `<div class="item mbtn download-movie pull-right" style=""> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download </div>`